# How to populate a table view with an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I copied sample code to create an objective-c table in my app (http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/).  The example works great.

The issue I have is that the example uses a predefined array of items, but my app generates the array item list when the view controller is loaded.

My app is generating a list of movie credits in:

```
NSMutableArray *creditList;
```

In viewDidLoad I have:

```
creditList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test Movie 1", nil];
```

Then I generate the movie list.  When the loop is complete, the list is stored correctly in array creditList as determined by:

```
NSLog(@"creditList array: %@", creditList);
```

How do I now populate the table with the list of items generated and where would I put that code?

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Answer (score 4):

So here are the steps

1. first you have to have the tableview and have a reusable identifier in this case i just called it "cell"
   [image]
2. Since you already have the array and the values in the array you have now to set the sections and rows as you can see in this code

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;    
      } 

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
          return creditList.count; 
      }
   ```
3. now you have to set up the actual cell with this code

   ```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];

        return cell;
     }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your steps.  Since they were essentially the same steps in the example link I provided, I am getting the same result (which you show in Step 4) where only the initial contents of the array are shown and not the complete array that I see when I use: NSLog(@"creditList array: %@", creditList);

Comment: Hi @lee so basically you are getting the movies from a web service right?

Comment: Yes Cesar, they are pulled using the TMDb API and come back as a JSON response.  Here is the code that populates the array:

    while (myCount < movieCount) {
                       if ([fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"media_type"]   isEqual: @"movie"]) {
                           NSLog(@"Movie Title: %@", fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"title"]);
                           creditTitle = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"title"];
                           [creditList addObject:creditTitle];

Comment: so first in the viewdidload just put [[NSMutable Array alloc]init]; then in the method were you fill the array put the [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: I added [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; into the viewDidLoad and I got a soft warning of 'Expression result unused'.  I also added '[self.tableView reloadData];' after I post NSLOG showing the correct creditList.  When I ran the app, it still just showed the original contents of creditList ('Test Movie 1).  I appreciate your efforts in helping, Cesar.

Comment: could you update the post so with the current code of the tableviewcontroller that you have so i could help you more! @Lee

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want me to paste the whole of the CelebrityDetailViewController.m file that I have been editing? I did try to switch this to a chat instead but apparently I need 20 rep first.

Comment: you could paste just the viewDidLoad, the method were you get the info of the credit list and the cellForRowAtIndexPath @Lee

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/94876/how-to-populate-a-table-view-with-an-nsmutablearray?tab=general 

@Lee here's the chat room

Comment: I get a message that it's too many characters to paste.  Try this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7rfg2dy7jjpr8q/ViewDidLoad.rtf?dl=0

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here."

Comment: ohh darn it! we won't be able to have a chat @Lee

Comment: okay so you have the array fill after you do the JLTMDbClient get right? and were you print the array it display everything that you put in it?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
 });

Comment: Yes and yes.  I pasted your code after the NSLOG line and it still just shows Test Movie 1  :(

Comment: ohh yeah i think i saw the problem you need to set the creditList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; and remove the line with the creditList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test Movie 1", nil]; after you do this just refresh the table!

Comment: Ok so I replaced the old creditlist line with:

    creditList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

but now the list is blank :(

Comment: the init has to have a space between the bracket and the word probably thats why it didn't was instantiated creditList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: This list does NOT want to display!  Still the same, even with the added space.

Comment: could you take a picture of the tableview and could you post the method of cellForRowAtIndexPath @Lee

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7pm5qr2m4zuhow/Screenshot%202015-11-12%2005.17.58.png?dl=0 

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

Comment: okay that method should be fine, but you might have to put some breakpoints along in the code, so you can check what is going on so for example you can place some break points at the moment of creating the array, another one at the moment of filling the array, and other one when you create the cell, so probably for this thing that you're making you won't need the self.tableview reloadData because you are getting it at the moment when the view loads, so put those breakpoints and just see what happens when you're getting something wrong and those stuff

Comment: Ok well I do appreciate the time you spent reviewing my issue.  Thanks Cesar.

Comment: No problem man that's what we're for! Sorry about not gettint to solve the problem tho! @Lee

Comment: This site is a great resource, just the history of answers alone makes it so valuable.  I'll get it figured out and come back and provide the answer when I do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSMutableArray` same as `NSArray`. No need to do anything more.

After the items are generated. You just need to call:

`[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I place that code in viewDidLoad after the NSLOG statement, I get "Unknown receiver 'tableview'; did you mean 'UITableView'?" If I change it to UITableView then I get "No known class method for selector 'reloadData'".

Comment: `tableView` is a handler of `UITableView`.

Comment: `[tableView reloadData];`  .. It helped

Answer (score 0):

To populate a table with your data a common design pattern to use  is UITableViewDelegate, in your implementation (.m) file add the delegates like so :

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Then call two functions in the same ViewController.m file, the first of which is :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_creditList count];
  }
```

The second function :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
          static NSString *cellName = @"cellNamedInStoryBoard";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];

       if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellName];
       } 

      cell.textLabel.text = [_creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSLog(@"cell label created");

      return cell;
   }
```

You will need to set dataSource and the delegate in your storyboard which you can you can do by right clicking and dragging your table view to the yellow ViewController icon and selecting both the delegate and dataSource.

Once you've done that, provided your array is populated with strings , you should see the items listed in table view when you run the app.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive response.  Everything you detailed was almost line for line what I had and was in the link I provided of the example I used.  Unfortunately due to that, all I still show on the table is "Test Movie 1".